# How to register a forward hook for PyTorch matmul?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, torch

`torch.matmul` doesn't seem to have an `nn.Module` wrapper to allow the standard forward hook registration by name. In this case, the matrix multiply happens in the middle of a `forward()` function. I suppose the intermediate result can be returned by `forward()` in addition to the final result, such as `return x, mm_res`. But what's a good way to collect these additional outputs?

What are the options for offloading `torch.matmul` outputs? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your primary complaint is the fact that `torch.matmul` doesn't have a Module wrapper, how about just making one

```
class Matmul(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, *args):
        return torch.matmul(*args)
```

Now you can register a forward hook on a `Matmul` instance

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.matmul = Matmul()
        self.matmul.register_module_forward_hook(...)
    def forward(self, x):
        y = ...
        z = self.matmul(x, y)
        ...
```

Being said that, you must not overlook the warning (in red) [in the doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_forward_hook.html) that it should only be used for debugging purpose.